# How to generate concentric layers in a matrix

Tags: java, loops, matrix

I need to generate a matrix with this aspect:

[image]

But with more layers and I can't find a way to do it.
To understand, each color has `n` layers (in this example, `n=2`), and there can be `m` colors (in this example, `m=3`). The inner matrix, the green one, should follow the same spiral pattern as the others, in the image is wrong. The next color, yellow in this case, needs to start "surrounding" the previous matrix starting in the top left, filling one layer and continuing the next "layer" in the top left too, and so on.
The colors itself aren't important, what is important are the numbers in each cell.

Any ideas?

PS: Forget the 10 and 34 in green, those are just modifications.

PS2: This example was filled by hand, which is something I can do for this size of matrix, but for a 256x256 would be impossible.

Comment: No, that's actually a mistake I hadn't noticed. They should follow the same rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy would be to start with the innermost layer, and fill them while going outwards. This way, the core loop becomes particularly simple, because you can just walk through the relevant part of the matrix, and fill only the fields that are *not* filled yet.

The "relevant" part of the matrix can be computed easily within loops over the colors an layers: With each layer, the total size (width and height) of the rectangle that is covered by one layer increases by 2. When the desired number of layers has been filled, the "counter" that is used to fill the matrix is reset to zero, to indicate that a new color starts.

An example:

```
public class LayeredMatrix
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test(1,1);
        test(2,2);
        test(3,3);
        test(2,3);
    }

    private static void test(int layers, int colors)
    {
        System.out.println(layers+" layers, "+colors+" colors");
        print(generate(layers, colors));
    }

    private static int[][] generate(int layers, int colors)
    {
        int size = layers * colors * 2;
        int matrix[][] = new int[size][size];
        int layerSize = 2;
        for (int color=0; color<colors; color++)
        {
            int colorOffset = (colors - color - 1) * layers;
            int counter = 1;
            for (int layer = 0; layer < layers; layer++)
            {
                int layerOffset = layers - layer - 1;
                int r0 = colorOffset + layerOffset;
                int c0 = colorOffset + layerOffset;
                int r1 = r0 + layerSize;
                int c1 = c0 + layerSize;
                for (int r=r0; r<r1; r++)
                {
                    for (int c=c0; c<c1; c++)
                    {
                        if (matrix[r][c] == 0)
                        {
                            matrix[r][c] = counter;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                layerSize += 2;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    private static void print(int matrix[][])
    {
        for (int r=0; r<matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%4d", matrix[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

For the case depicted in the question, it prints

```
2 layers, 3 colors
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
  49   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  50
  51  11  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  12  52
  53  13  29   1   2   3   4   5   6  30  14  54
  55  15  31   7   5   6   7   8   8  32  16  56
  57  17  33   9   9   1   2  10  10  34  18  58
  59  19  35  11  11   3   4  12  12  36  20  60
  61  21  37  13  13  14  15  16  14  38  22  62
  63  23  39  15  16  17  18  19  20  40  24  64
  65  25  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  26  66
  67  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  68
  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
```